# Not able to find GWT bootstrap3 FlexTable

Tags: gwtbootstrap3

Any one have any idea of something like `FlexTable` in GWT Bootstrap3.
I searched a lot , but not able to find a flextable thing in  GWT Bootstrap3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), Gwtbootstrap3 is using [it as well](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#gridSystem).

You can setup you base grid with UiBinder:

```
<b:Container ui:field="container">
  <b:Row>
    <b:Column size="MD_4">...</b:Column>
    <b:Column size="MD_4">...</b:Column>
  </b:Row>
</b:Container>
```

The easily add rows and columns programmatically:

```
@UiField
Container container;

Row row = new Row();

Column column = new Column(ColumnSize.MD_4);
column.add(new Label("Test"));

row.add(column);
container.add(row);
```

So you can setup and alter grids as you please.